# error Bad Gateway NGINX 502 PHP-FPM fastcgi

Tags: php, html, nginx, fastcgi, fpm

My boss was messing around with this page and suddenly it stopped working and started giving us a 502 Bad Gateway error. Is there anything you can see that explains why this happened?

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="?p=tenuta_a_deo.html">About A Deo</a></li>

<li>
    <a href="?p=our_wines">Our Wines</a>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="?p=our_wines/tenuta_a_deo_red.html">Tenuta A Deo - Red</a></li>

        <li><a href="?p=our_wines/tenuta_a_deo_white.html">Tenuta A Deo - White</a></li>

        <li><a href="?p=our_wines/tenuta_a_deo_oil.html">Tenuta A Deo - Oil</a></li>

        <li><a href="?p=our_wines/popova_kula.html">Popova Kula</a></li>

        <li><a href="?p=our_wines/kokino.html">Kokino</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>



<li><a href="?p=lucca_olive_oil.html">Lucca Olive Oil</a></li>



<li>
    <a href="?p=vacation_rentals">The Farm</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="?p=vacation_rentals/villa_lucca.html">Villa Lucca</a></li>
        <li><a href="?p=vacation_rentals/casa_casciani.html">Casa Casciani</a></li>
        <li><a href="?p=vacation_rentals/tenuta_a_deo.html">Tenuta A Deo</a></li>
        <li><a href="?p=vacation_rentals/tourist_information.html">Tourist information</a></li>

    </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="?p=how_to_purchase.html">How to Purchase</a></li>


<li><a href="?p=gallery.php">Gallery</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: p=vacation_rentals has no extension??

Comment: p=our_wines neither - that is not the problem.

Comment: When getting a `50{x}` error, check the error logs for an explanation. This is most likely not caused by some HTML code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A `502 Bad Gateway` error is **not caused by static HTML** like you just displayed.

The server was probably having an internal error or an error communicating with other servers - maybe there was a (temporary) overload, or another server/service was not reachable. Does it still happen when you clear your cache or use another browser/computer?

Can you tell us more about your webserver, and its links to other servers/services?

Comment: I wish I could, the person who takes care of our servers is on holiday... knowing this did help a lot though. Thanks for the help.
p.s. no, changing browsers/computers/clearing the cache did not work.

Comment: Then check out Andreas' answer: a router or malfunctioning networking device might also be the cause. You might want to change your question a bit, you wouldn't want that F-word to be there when your (future) boss visits this page...

Comment: Acctually my boss told me to use the f word, thanks for the pointer though :). I managed to contact our guy and he seemed to know exactly what was wrong and promised to fix it tonight. Thanks for the links though.

Comment: I guess it stands for "fooling around" then ;D

Answer (score 10):

The cause for the `502` is not on the page. Looks more like a configuration issue, either on the server or on a network component (router).

Answer (score 0):

find the php-cgi file from PHP directory in C drive then go to your IDE and follow the step below:

settings->Language & Frameworks->PHP->CLI interpreter->C:\PHP7\php-cgi